# Selenium Validate element value when using Page Object Model C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm building a test suite with Selenium (Nunit) C# using page object model and page factory. I'm trying to figure out the best way in a test to validate the values in certain fields (elements) on a page.

e.g.

```
public class OrderPage
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Username")]
    private IWebElement usernameField;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "ValidToDateTime")]
    private IWebElement dateToField;


    public string validateField() //method to validate field
    {
        string field = usernameField.GetAttribute("text");

        return field;
    }
}
```

And the calling test:-

```
[Test]
public void checkFields()
{

  string username = "Smith";
  string toDate = "14th June";

  // check the content of the Username field is correct
  string content = Pages.OP.validateField();
  Assert.IsTrue(content.Contains(username));

  // check the content of the ValidToDateTime field is correct ...etc...


}
```

I've simplified the code but basically the Order page has multiple text fields which contain text data. The [Test] is reading in some data (see string username and toDate) and the test needs to check the text on the page matches the data read into the Test.

I need to understand the correct approach when using a Page Object model e.g. should i write one method with the webelements hardcoded to validate all the necessary fields? Should the validation occur in OrderPage.validateField method and return true/false or should it return the value and the [Test] does the validation?

This is more an OO approach question - how would you do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is I have a Validations object that holds methods related to validation and then a Report object that holds methods related to reporting (this is related to generating html reports at the end of a test run).

My Validations object looks like this:

```
public class Validations
    {
        private HtmlReport htmlReport;
        private MsTESTReport msTestReport;

        public Validations(HtmlReport htmlReport, MsTESTReport msTestReport)
        {

            this.htmlReport = htmlReport;
            this.msTestReport = msTestReport;

        }

        public void assertionPass(string stepName, string message)
        {
            htmlReport.reportPassEvent(stepName, message);
        }

        public void assertionFailed(string stepName, string message)
        {
            AssertFailedException assertionFailedError = getAssertionFailedErrorObject(stepName, message);
            htmlReport.reportFailEvent(stepName, message);
            msTestReport.reportAssertionFailed(assertionFailedError);
        }

        private AssertFailedException getAssertionFailedErrorObject(string stepName, string errorMessage)
        {
            string message = "StepName: " + stepName + "\n ErrorMessage : " + errorMessage;
            AssertFailedException assertionFailedError = new AssertFailedException(message);
            return assertionFailedError;
        }
    }
```

Note: you don't have to include all the reporting like I did this is just an example of what my validations object looks like. You could just output the results to the console when the test passes and throw an AssertionFailedException when the test fails instead.

And it is typically called like this in a method within a page object class:

```
    public class OrderPage : Page
    {
        [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Username")]
        private IWebElement usernameField;

        [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "ValidToDateTime")]
        private IWebElement dateToField;

public OffersPage(IWebDriver browser, Report report, Validations validations)
            : base(browser, report, validations)
        {
            //Constructor
        }


        public string validateField(string expectedText) //method to validate field
        {
            try
           {
               string actualText = usernameField.GetAttribute("text");
               if (actualText.ToLower().Trim().Equals(expectedText))
               {
                   validations.assertionPass("validateField", "Expected text displays as expected.");
                }
                else
                {
                    validations.assertionFailed("validateField", "The expected text does not display as expected " + actualText + " displays instead.");
                }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              //this is typically where I put my report method
              //but I'm not including it in the rest of the example 
              //because you didn't ask how to generate reports and this 
              //is just a way to put the exception thrown in the html 
              //report. You could just as easily throw the exception 
               //here if need be
              report.reportException(ex, "validateField");
           }
    }
```

Then you would call it in the test method like so:

```
public class SomeTest : CommonSteps 
{
    public SomeTest()
       :base()
    {
       //Constructor
    }

    [Test]
    public void checkFields()
    {
        //Instantiate your OrderPage object in a CommonMethods class 
        //you would also instantiate and set up your Validation/Report objects 
        //so they could be passed down through the page objects
       //You would also open the browser, basically any before and after test 
       //set up in the CommonMethods class
       //Your test class would then inherit the CommonMethods class and it 
       //would start at the test itself.

        //oPage is declared in CommonMethods
        oPage.validateField("Smith");

    }
}
```

A brief example of CommonMethod class would be something like:

```
 public class CommonSteps
    {
        protected IWebDriver browser;
        protected HomePage homePage;
        protected Validations validations;

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            //code to initializeBrowser();

             //code to initializevalidationsObject();

             //code to openApplication();

        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            try
            {
                //code to close the application safely
            }
            catch (WebDriverException)
            {

            }

            finally
            {

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post, very useful.